# filter with yes ,no and all in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres like

```
id phone_number
1 null
2 444444444
3 null
4 48572444444
5 4822555555
```

and there is a filter like has_value.Filter contain 3 value '**Yes**','**No**' and '**Select All**'.I want to filter data on basis of this filter if '**yes**' then shown all id and mobile number which have a mobile number. if '**no**' it must show null mobile number.if 'All' then all record.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide an example that we can reproduce.

Comment: @ganpat just tell us how your `filter` looks like, is it parameter? are you doing this in select? you got some variable? how you run query? from some application or something 3rd?

Comment: @Veljko89 filter is a parameter.It is running from pentaho bi server.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** should be

```
where phone_number is not null
```

**No** should be

```
where phone_number is null
```

**Select All** shoud be nothing, or well

```
where 1=1
```

If you want to use a parameter having 'yes', 'no' or 'all', use:

```
case when ('yes'= lower($1)) then (phone_number is not null) 
     when ('no'=lower($1)) then (phone_number is null) 
     else true end
```

Comment: `where 1=1` can be simplified to `where true`

Comment: I need 3 cases in single because yes and no coming from the parameter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you're right. Even better, your suggestion may have a better performance